# R, zoo with performance analytics

Tags: r, zoo, performanceanalytics

How can I use a `zoo` object with [the `PerformanceAnalytics` package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=PerformanceAnalytics)?
It says that I need a timeseries but I can convert it properly.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code example using the `PerformanceAnalytics` function `Return.annualized`  suggests that

1. `PerformanceAnalytics` does work with `zoo` objects (in fact the `manager` dataset used as an example in the manual turns out to be a `zoo` object)
2. It should be possible to convert a `zoo` object into a `ts` object and get the same results

So if you still have a problem, you will need to illustrate it in more detail

```
> library(PerformanceAnalytics)
> library(zoo)
> 
> set.seed(1)
> x.date <- as.Date(paste(2003, 2, c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14), sep = "-"))
> xzoo <- zoo(runif(5), x.date)
> xzoo
2003-02-01 2003-02-03 2003-02-07 2003-02-09 2003-02-14 
 0.2655087  0.3721239  0.5728534  0.9082078  0.2016819 
> is.ts(xzoo)
[1] FALSE
> is.zoo(xzoo)
[1] TRUE
> Return.annualized(xzoo)
                       [,1]
Annualized Return 193340828
> 
> xts <- as.ts(xzoo)
> xts
Time Series:
Start = 12084 
End = 12097 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 0.2655087        NA 0.3721239        NA        NA        NA 0.5728534        NA 0.9082078
[10]        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.2016819
> is.ts(xts)
[1] TRUE
> is.zoo(xts)
[1] FALSE
> Return.annualized(xts)
                       [,1]
Annualized Return 193340828
```